# MongoDB: use of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

TLDR; Should you use subdocuments or relational Id?

This is my `Post`Schema:

```
const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  comments: [Comment.schema]
})
```

And this is my `Comment` Schema:

```
const Comment = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
```

In Postgres, I would have a `post_id` field in `Comment`, instead of having an array of comments inside `Post`. I am sure you can do the same in MongoDB but I don't know which one is more conventional. If people use subdocuments over references (and joining tables) in MongoDB, why is that? In other words, why should I ever use subdocuments? If it's advantageous, should I do the same in Postgres as well?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, answering based on that.

If you will keep `sub documents`, you don't have to query two tables to know `comments specific to one post`.

Let's say we have following db structure for post:-

```
[{
  _id:1,
  title:'some title',
  comments:[
    {
      ...//some fields that belongs to comments
    } ,
    {
      ...//some fields that belongs to comments
    } ,
    ...
  ]
},
{
  _id:2,
  title:'some title',
  comments:[
    {
      ...//some fields that belongs to comments
    } ,
    {
      ...//some fields that belongs to comments
    } ,
    ...
  ]
}]
```

Now you can query based on `_id` of the `post` (1) and can get `comments array` that belongs to the specific post.

If you will just keep the `comment's id` inside post, you have to query both the tables, which I don't think is a good idea.

***EDIT :-***

If you are keeping `post id` inside `comments` record, then it will help you to track which comment is for which post i.e. if you want to query comments table based on `post id` and you need only fields from comments records.

What I think, use case will be which post contains what all comments. So keeping comment inside post will give you comments fields as well as fields from post record.

So it's totally depends on your requirement, how you will design your data structure.

Comment: "If you will just keep the comment's id inside post, you have to query both the tables, which I don't think is a good idea." -- isn't that what you always do in relational DBs? Even in MongoDB, you can do that same by using `populate()`.

Comment: Oh, I think you might have meant the other way around? I am asking whether having `post_id` field inside `Comment` makes more sense than having an array of comments inside `Post`.

Comment: That is based on your requirement. Whether you will query frequently posts table or comment table.